# Generate button states dynamically.

Tags: android, button

I have some buttons which are just simple png-files. They look like they have default `normal` state. I want to create `pressed` state for every button dynamically. The main aim is to avoid working with png and designer.
How can I create `Pressed` state using xml or java?

Comment: Do you have images for "normal" and "pressed" or do you want to avoid creating pictures? I don't get it...

Comment: I don't have pressed images and don't want to create them!

Comment: search what selector is

Comment: I suppose you could just change the alpha of your image that you have with touch events on your Button that trigger off of touchDown and touchUp events.  Or something similar to that if that is what you are asking.

Comment: I was thinking about alpha. How can I mix original drawable with alpha or any mask in selector?

Comment: Even google use different images, see here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList So I don't think there is another way to get the same effect

Answer (score 0):

If however, you are looking for XML code for triggering different imagery based on states, then a selector placed in your res->drawable folder would do the trick.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/gallerydisabled" />
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/gallerypressed" />
    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/gallerynormal" />
</selector>
```

Comment: I don't have pictures for all button states